# Validate LESS string in PHP

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, less

I'm working in a site developed in cakephp, where I have a page to save a less file (css) into my database.
What I want to do is to validate less string before save into my database (into the model) in PHP.

Is there a way to validate a LESS string in php to understand if there is some error and stop my save?

my function is something like that into the model:

```
public function beforeSave(){
        if (isset($this->data['Widget']['code_less'])){
            //I want here to check if the less string is a valid less 
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I have seen lessphp project but i don't want to save my less into a file or something like that, I only want to validate a LESS string not a file.

Thanks

Comment: `lessphp` compiles files and strings. It also throws exception on invalid files. See http://leafo.net/lessphp/docs/#php_interface (Error Handling section)

Comment: I have seen but the plugin for cakephp don't do this thing @dev-null-dweller or in the manual of that isn't specified

Comment: So change the plugin for one that exposes full potential of the library, or include file with `lessc` and use it directly.

Comment: Yes I'm tryng already to do this thing, I hope that is the good way @dev-null-dweller

Comment: a little bit off topic, but seems custom validator will be more suitable, then `beforeSave`. Here how to build custom validators http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#custom-validation-rules

Answer (score 1):

Using the suggestion of @vadim and create a custom validator with a custom function.

As mentioned by @dev-null-dweller [Lessphp](http://leafo.net/lessphp/) offers an option to do this:

```
validateless($lesscode)
{
   $less = new lessc;
   try {
      $less->compile($lesscode);
   }
   catch (Exception $ex) {
      return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

Lessphp 0.4 supports Less version < 1.4.2 now. Although not using the latest version of LESS the result in most cases will be good enough to valid a simple string of less code.   [Less.php](https://github.com/oyejorge/less.php) supports LESS v 1.4.2. (which also compiles Twitter's Bootstrap > 3.0.0.). Less.php doesn't support validation. Passing only one rule of less each time, will result in a empty string when the code is invalid. Checking multiple rules / lines once doesn't seem possible.

An other option will be to install Less on your server and call the bundled compiler with a php system call.
Install LESS: `npm install -g less`

```
validateless($lesscode)
{
   exec('echo "'.$lesscode.'" | lessc -',$output,$error);
   return ($error>0)?false:true;
}
```